# Dedupe rules with Form Processor?

Tags: form-processor

Can I use a Dedupe rule with Form Processor? I haven't found any such option in the Action options. If not, which is the default Dedupe rule used? The automatic one?

Comment: dedupe would normally use the unsupervised one in a situation where you are not offered an option to make the judgement call

Comment: thanks Pete, we'll test having this core configuration in mind

Comment: Did you get a clue? If I repost same data to action CreateOrUpdateOrganization it is always creating a new item...

Comment: I wrote an action myself. thx!

Comment: I think I never found exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the Extended Contact Matcher extension (https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.xcm, documentation: https://docs.civicrm.org/xcm/en/latest/). That will also add an action to Find or Create a contact using the XCM profile. And the Extended Contact Matcher will allow you to use dedupe rules.

[image]

Comment: this sounds great! thanks Erik.

Answer (score 2):

(I don't have a reputation to add a comment but want to share this with others who want to know how to update rather than create contacts that exist.)

If you are attempting to update organizations rather than duplicate them, I find the following updates organizations correctly.

1. Select 'Contact: Get organization by name' to get the CID for the organization by setting the Parameter Mapping: Organization Name to the input field that contains my organization name.
2. Select 'Contact: Create or update Organization' to update the values by setting the Parameter Mapping: Contact ID field to the Action you create in step 1. Notice that it says "Leave empty to create a new Organization." Thus, if the action from step 1 finds an organization contact that matches your organization input field, then that action will contain the CID for the organization and be updated. Otherwise, a new record will be created.

[image: image of step 2]

As far as options for deduping, the action used in step 1 only uses the organization name. For individual contacts, I found that the 'Contact: Get Individual by name and email' action will let me choose whether the contact has to be an exact match of all three or not. (I use this to get the CID of the individual contact and then 'Contact: Create or update Individual' to update the contact by setting the Parameter Mapping: Contact ID field to the action that contains the individual contact ID.

Comment: definitely worth giving a try! thanks Charlotta

Comment: Great, works also for individuals, thanks.